# ge vs double equal in bash

Tags: bash, operators

I am trying to solve a hackerrank exercise.

```
If n is odd, print Weird
If n is even and in the inclusive range of 2 to 5, print Not Weird
If n is even and in the inclusive range of 6 to 20, print Weird
If n is even and greater than 20, print Not Weird
```

My code is as follows:

```
read n
if [ $n%2==0 ]; then
    if [ $n -ge 6 ] && [ $n -le 20 ]; then
        echo "Weird"
    else
        echo "Not Weird"
    fi
else
    echo "Weird"
fi
```

When I give the input as `3`, the result I get is `Not Weird` which is not correct same for `1` I get Not Weird. However, when I try this:

```
read n
if [ $(($n%2)) -eq 0 ]; then
    if [ $n -ge 6 ] && [ $n -le 20 ]; then
        echo "Weird"
    else
        echo "Not Weird"
    fi
else
    echo "Weird"
fi
```

I get the right result. What is the difference?

Comment: Please s post what is your goal to achieve? With sample Input_file and expected sample output.

Comment: Why would you use `$((...))` to perform math in one but not the other? Also, you need whitespace around `==` just as you put whitespace around `-eq`. `[ $(( n % 2)) == 0 ]` (which while not recommended, will work as long as the result of `$(( n % 2 ))` is the literal string `0`, not `00` or some other string representing 0).

Comment: `==`is the operator for String comparison. `-eq`is the operator for integer comparison. `-ge`means `greater or equal`and is thus not the same thing at all.

Comment: You can simplify your two cases to just the first `if` in each example - the rest of the code only serves to make the question harder to read.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**`[` `]` (or `test`) builtin:**

`==`, or to be POSIX compliant `=`, does a *string* comparison

`-eq` does a numeric comparison

Note:  `==` and `-eq` (and other comparisons) are *parameters* to the `[` command, so they *must* be separated by whitespace, so `$n%2==0` is invalid.

**`[[` `]]` keyword:**

is as `[` except that it does pattern matching.  Being a keyword rather than a builtin, expansion with `[[` is done earlier in the scan.

**`((` `))` syntax**

Carries out arithmetic evaluation as with the `let` builtin.  Whitespace separators are not mandatory.  Using a leading `$` to expand a variable is not necessary and is not recommended since it changes the expansion order.

Comment: Other relevant diffs: `[ ]` does not evaluate numeric expressions (e.g. `$n%2`); `[[ ]]` does *if* they're operands to a numeric comparison like `-eq`; `(( ))` always does. Also, in `[ ]`, `=` is (string) comparison and `==` *might* be a synonym; in `[[ ]]` they're both string comparison, while in `(( ))`, `==` is numeric comparison an `=` is variable assignment.

Answer (score 0):

For truth evaluation inside `if-else`,  `bash` provides `((..))` operators with no need of a `$` on the front.

```
n=5
if (( (n % 2) == 0 )); then
    echo "Something"
    if (( n >= 6 )) && (( n <= 20 )); then
        echo "Some other thing"
    else
        echo "Other else thing"
    fi
else
    echo "Something else"
fi
```

Read [here](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/arith_expr) for more information.